# Progressbar databinding can't change the visibility

Tags: android, data-binding

I have a progressbar in my layout in Android and i want to change its visibility inside the viewmodel. But application only gets the first state of progressbar. Whenever i try to change it nothing happen. Here is my layout file ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"></import>
        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.ui.auth.AuthViewModel"  />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="24dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="154dp"
                android:layout_height="154dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                android:src="@drawable/bexfalogo"
                android:contentDescription="@string/bexlogo" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="132dp"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:hint="@string/hint_username">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_text_username"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@={viewmodel.userName}"
                    >

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/password_text_input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:hint="@string/hint_password"
                app:errorEnabled="true">


                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_text_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:text="@={viewmodel.password}"

                    />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:id="@+id/button_login"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:text="@string/button_login"
                    android:onClick="@{viewmodel::onClickUserLogin}"
                    />

                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/button_login"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button_login"
                    android:text="@string/button_cancel" />

            </RelativeLayout>
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="@{viewmodel.isLoading ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

and my viewmodel looks like this

```
package com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.ui.auth

import android.content.Intent
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.databinding.BaseObservable
import androidx.databinding.Bindable
import androidx.databinding.ObservableBoolean
import androidx.databinding.library.baseAdapters.BR
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.data.network.repositories.AuthorizeSessionRepository
import com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.ui.home.HomeActivity
import com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.util.ApiException
import com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.util.NoInternetException
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import okhttp3.internal.notify

class AuthViewModel (
    private val repository: AuthorizeSessionRepository

):ViewModel() {



   var userName: String?=null
    var password: String?=null
    val isLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>(true)


    fun onClickUserLogin(view: View){
        isLoading.value = false
        val sessionID = 0
        val authorityID = 0
        val loginType = "System"



        viewModelScope.launch {
            if(!(userName==null||password==null)){
            try{
                 val authResponse = userLogin(sessionID,authorityID,userName!!,password!!,loginType)
                if(authResponse.Result){
                    isLoading.value=false
                    Toast.makeText(view.context, "Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    val intent = Intent(view.context,HomeActivity::class.java)
                    view.context.startActivity(intent)
                }else{
                    //isLoading.value=false
                    Toast.makeText(view.context, "Login Failed!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }catch (e: ApiException){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }catch (e: NoInternetException){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }}
            else{
                Toast.makeText(view.context, "Kullanıcı adı ve şifre boş bırakılamaz!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
}

suspend fun userLogin(
SessionID : Int,
AuthorityID: Int,
UserName: String,
Password : String,
LoginType: String
)= withContext(Dispatchers.IO){repository.userLogin(SessionID, AuthorityID, UserName, Password, LoginType)}
}
```

As i mentioned it is just get the first state but when i click the button nothing changes..

Comment: You are never setting the isLoading to true again, check this.

Comment: It doesn't matter. I mean this code supposed to show progressbar at the beginning(it shows) and make it invisible after i clicked onClickUserLogin(). But it doesn't make it invisible after i click.

Comment: It looks everything ok, is getting the method `onClickUserLogin()` called? I mean, are you calling correctly your viewModel from your fragment / activity?

Comment: Yes i am using this method with databinding. I bind my ViewModel to my layout. And i am calling it from ViewModel. I find a way to do this by observing the isLoading from my activity. It works fine but i am wondering why this way is not working